# glob.glob print returns unknown character block

Tags: python-3.x, glob

When I run my function, it shows the tuple as being empty, even though it should find something in the directory.

The first function "check_files('\\SERVER1\C$\DIRECTORY\', '*.pdf', 'Test 0')" Returns TRUE, since there is a file in the directory.

For the following functions, it returns FALSE, even though there are files in the directory. Doing a print statement of "Output" it shows

[image: CHARACTER]

This makes me think it cant find the directory and throwing the whole thing off.

What gives??

```
import os
import glob

def check_files(mydir, myext, name):
     check = mydir + myext
     print(str(check))
     Output = glob.glob(check)
          if Output == []: #FALSE
               print (str(name) + 'All Operational.')
          else: #TRUE
               print (str(name) + 'I see some files here, please check the process.')



check_files('\\\SERVER1\\C$\\DIRECTORY\\', '*.pdf', 'Test 0')
check_files('\\\10.2.2.1\\Directory\\', '*.pdf', 'Test 1: ')
check_files('\\\10.3.2.1\\Directory\\', '*.pdf', 'Test 2: ')
check_files('\\\10.4.2.1\\Directory\\', '*.pdf', 'Test 3: ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape all of the `\` characters.  Try running `print('\1')` to see why.

```
check_files('\\\\10.2.2.1\\Directory\\', '*.pdf', 'Test 1: ')
```

etc.

Comment: That was it my friend. Thank you very much!